# Have to receive WhatsApp message with old cell phone (no android phone)

Tags: android, phone, whatsapp

My android phone has had some problem, so I like to ask about how could  receive my WhatsApp message by old cell phone like below:
[image]
I guess it could be done by installing some androids simulator on my Ubuntu 18.04 OS and inserting the activation SMS received form old cell phone.

So, I asked here for your solution and more comment to doing this job.
Thanks.

Comment: This is more a question for android.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could try to install Android x86 in a virtual machine in Ubuntu (with VirtualBox or Gnome Boxes), install WhatsApp there, and see if you can activate via the SMS in the old phone as you say. But this wouldn't be an Ubuntu-specific question.

Comment: Thanks, I have asked on android SE site ([here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239165/have-to-receive-whatsapp-message-with-old-cell-phone-no-android-phone)), and I guess this question could be closed, but asked for sure.